# React change text dynamically for component

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange, rerender

I have a react component that is pulling data from a database every 4 seconds causing a state change and re-render. However, I have some text that I would like to be able to click and edit without the re-render interrupting it. I currently have this for the text change...

```
const [name, setName] = useState("name")

handleChange(event) {
  setName(event.target.value);
}
  
render() {
  return (
    <form>
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

This works, however it gets interrupted and resets when my component re-renders. Do I need to temporarily disable rendering until the input field is submitted? And if so how do I do this? Or is there a simpler option?

Comment: Could you include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question? It's difficult to say what might be causing this issue from the code currently in your question. It might be that your component is remounted or something else entirely.

Comment: It is a lot of code to show everything but basically my app is calling an Axios.post and Axios.get to get data from a database every 4 seconds. This updates the entire component even if I am in the middle inputing the text field. Make sense?

Comment: I understand, but it's difficult to say from the code currently in your question what might be wrong, so it will be hard for anyone to help you. If you boil down your code to something that still gives rise to your error it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: I understand, but I am not sure how to do that without posting hundreds of lines of code. It is pretty simple concept though. I have a component that renders every n seconds. However, when someone is changing text, I need to disable this somehow until they have completed their changes.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to send them to a clone of the current component that has everything except the axios requests and it redirects them back to the app after they are done with the inputs.

Comment: Have you tried moving your -interval updating component- to another module and updating it without alerting the parent component?

Comment: It's a little hard to exactly understand what you want, but I would suggest having some sort of a countdown, and every time the input field is changed - you set a countdown of 2 seconds in which you do not perform the `get` request.

Comment: These are both good suggestions. I will try both of them. Thanks!

Comment: probably you can use some Boolean state that checks whether the input is in focus or not. If focus is true, you can set the Boolean value accordingly and based on this Boolean value you may or may not hit the api.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit difficult to determine the solution from the code provided, but as far as I know you are calling **setInterval** to call an **API** every 4s and after that saving it in some state which is triggering a **re-render**, now when re-rendering happens the text value gets reset. As far as I know, the value of state do not gets reinitialized on re-render, I mean that breaks the purpose of using state in React.

Your textfield value depends on name which is a state, so it should not get reinitialized.
But again, I do not know the structure of your project, so cannot tell that why is state getting reinitialized on re-render

**Solution:**
It is more like a hack, but what you can do is to use the setInterval and setTimeout in handleChange function.

**Tested, it is working fine**

```
let timer = null;
let timeout = null; 
const App = () => {
const [name, setName] = useState("name");
const [count, setCount] = useState(0); 

function handleChange(event) {

if (timer) {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
}
if(!timeout) timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(timeout);
  timeout = null;
  timer = setInterval(() => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  }, 500);
}, 2000); 
setName(event.target.value);

}
useEffect(() => {

timer = setInterval(() => {
  setCount(count => count + 1);
  }, 500)
}, [])  
 return (
<form>
  <p>{count}</p>
    <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
</form>
  )   ;
}
```